# Como inserir selecionando de duas tabelas diferentes?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

```
TABELA 1
- ID
- IMOVEL
- CODIGO
- IMAGEM_G  <----- nessa tabela este dado é vazio.
- IMAGEM_P

TABELA 2
- ID
- IMOVEL    <----- nessa tabela este dado é vazio.
- CODIGO    <----- nessa tabela este dado é vazio.
- IMAGEM_G
- IMAGEM_P
```

Preciso de uma `TABELA 3` assim:

```
- ID        <----- idêntico nas tabelas
- IMOVEL    <----- ID TABELA 1
- CODIGO    <----- ID TABELA 1
- IMAGEM_G  <----- ID TABELA 2
- IMAGEM_P  <----- idêntico nas tabelas
```

Podem me ajudar a montar esse `INSERT` na `TABELA 3`?

Comment: Isso vai vim de um formulário? Você já criou a 3ª tabela? Seria só fazer um insert normal com os dados que quer na tabela 3

Comment: Vou selecionar no próprio banco de dados e fazer insert destas infos numa terceira tabela dentro do banco.

Comment: Então é só fazer o SELECT dos dados que quer e depois o INSERT com o retorno dos dados na TAB_3, tipo uma procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode fazer um `INSERT SELECT` com os dados:

```
INSERT INTO `TABELA 3` (ID, IMOVEL, CODIGO, IMAGEM_G, IMAGEM_P)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.IMOVEL, t1,codigo, t2.IMAGEM_G, t1.IMAGEM_P FROM `TABELA 1` t1
INNER JOIN `TABELA 2` t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Considerando que `ID` é idêntico em ambas as tabelas e seus dados estão consistentes.

Comment: Com 2 ou 3 micro mexidas deu certo. Agora tenho outro problema. Tenho que fazer esse insert com 70MIL registros. Como eu posso dividir isso? Porque senão vai acabar com o banco de dados. A tendência desses registros é só aumentar.

Comment: Acha melhor colocar numa outra pergunta?

Comment: Marcos, cabe outra pergunta. Mas acredito que esse processo deva ser feito somente uma vez e que em seguida atualize sua aplicação para utilizar somente a `TABELA 3` no futuro, excluindo as tabelas anteriores.

Comment: Na verdade estou juntando informações das duas que por motivos de desempenho não cabem num único INSERT que é responsável pela geração das tabelas. É uma coisa que vou precisar fazer 1 vez por dia.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius acho interessante rever essa estratégia das tabelas. Por que não utilizar uma só? As vezes ao tentar resolver um problema criamos outros dois.

Comment: Podemos conversar sobre isso no chat?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius agora não vai ser possível, só conseguirei entrar na terça a noite.

Comment: Resumindo, tenho que pegar estes dados num webservice em duas consultas porque em uma consulta estoura o spool do webservice e dá erro. Por isso a necessidade de duas tabelas. Eu poderia fazer um update na segunda consulta mas ficou mais complexo pra mim do que usar duas tabelas.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius você precisa baixar esses dados todos os dias? 70 mil registros novos diários é muita coisa. Entre em contato com que disponibiliza o webservice e veja uma forma de baixar só os dados novos.

Answer (score 3):

Faça um select com o php para pegar os ids da `Tabela1` e, dentro de um loop, execute a `query` abaixo.

```
INSERT INTO Tabela3 (id, imovel, codigo, imagem_g, imagem_p)
    VALUES (
        (SELECT id FROM Tabela1 WHERE id = $id),
        (SELECT imovel FROM Tabela1 WHERE id = $id),
        (SELECT codigo FROM Tabela1 WHERE id = $id),
        (SELECT imagem_g FROM Tabela2 WHERE id = $id),
        (SELECT imagem_p FROM Tabela1 WHERE id = $id)
    )
```

Aconselho a colocar um `LIMIT` na quantidade de registros que será inserido por vez para não sobrecarregar o banco.

---

Outra forma seria, dentro do loop de ids da `Tabela1` pegar os dados via uma única consulta para depois inseri-los na `Tabela3`.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.imovel, t1.codigo, t2.imagem_g, t1.imagem_p
    FROM Tabela1 t1
    JOIN Tabela2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
        WHERE t1.id = $id

INSERT INTO Tabela3 (id, imovel, codigo, imagem_g, imagem_p)
    VALUES ($res->id, $res->imovel, $res->codigo, $res->imagem_g, $res->imagem_p)
```

Comment: Essa variavel `$id` não me diz nada porque eu vou selecionar os dados direto dentro do phpMyAdmin. Não entendo porque usá-lo!!!

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Você está querendo rodar esta consulta direto no banco/phpMyAdmin ou através do PHP?

Comment: Direto no phpMyAdmin porque eu já tenho centenas de registros prontos e só preciso fusionar as tabelas 1 e 2 na 3.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Sem utilizar alguma linguagem para percorrer os registros eu não sei como fazer, pois de alguma forma precisa de algum filtro para obter os valores. Vou remover a tag PHP da sua pergunta.